# Solve this equation $(1+Z)^5=(1-Z)^5$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Here is a question from a textbook I’m reading on complex numbers :

Solve this equation $$(1+Z)^5=(1-Z)^5$$

I’m new to the concept but I know how to solve $Z^n=p e^{i\theta}$
So how should I turn this to somthing I can go with ?

Even a hint would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Expand the products out and cancel terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left(\dfrac{1+Z}{1-Z}\right)^5 = 1 = e^{2 n\pi i} , n\in \Bbb{Z}$

$\Rightarrow\left(\dfrac{1+Z}{1-Z}\right) = e^{\frac{2 n\pi i}{5}}$

$\Rightarrow Z = \dfrac{e^{\frac{2 n\pi i}{5}}-1}{e^{\frac{2 n\pi i}{5}}+1}$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you conclude the third line from the second ?

Comment: @Negar It's componendo - Dividendo https://www.mathdoubts.com/componendo-and-dividendo/  ... Take $1+Z = a$, $1-Z = b$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: obviously $Z \ne -1$. Rearranging the equation:

$$\left(\frac {1-Z}{1+Z}\right)^5 = 1$$

Now $\dfrac {1-Z}{1+Z}$ is equal to some fifth root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{1+Z}{1-Z}=W$, then the equation is $W=1 \implies w=e^{2i\pi k/5}, k=0,1,2,3,4$. We get $$Z=\frac{W-1}{W+1}=\frac{e^{it}-1}{e^{it}+1}=i \tan (t/2),~ t=2i\pi k/5$$

Answer (score 1):

> \begin{align} (1+z)^5&=(1-z)^5 \tag{1}\label{1} \end{align}

According to
[the fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)
this single-variable, degree $5$ polynomial
with complex coefficients
(in this case real) has,
counted with multiplicity, exactly $5$ complex roots.

\begin{align} 
(1+z)^5-(1-z)^5
&=2\,z\,(z^4+10z^2+5)
\\
&=
2\,z\,
(z^2+5-2\sqrt5)(z^2+5+2\sqrt5)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Thus, all $5$ possible roots of \eqref{1} are:

\begin{align} 
z&=\left\{0, \pm\sqrt{-5+2\sqrt5}, \pm\sqrt{-5-2\sqrt5}
\right\}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}